# mutate_each: Standardize rows of data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I use `dplyr`to standardize every row of a data frame such that the row elements sum up to one?

I prefer to use `mutate_each` but the results are not correct as I specified them below. What is wrong?

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%select(-Species)%>%mutate_each(funs(./sum(.)))%>%head()

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1  0.005818597 0.007631923  0.002483591 0.001111729
2  0.005590416 0.006541648  0.002483591 0.001111729
3  0.005362236 0.006977758  0.002306191 0.001111729
4  0.005248146 0.006759703  0.002660990 0.001111729
5  0.005704507 0.007849978  0.002483591 0.001111729
6  0.006160867 0.008504143  0.003015789 0.002223457
```

Comment: Hi @muffin1974, looks like a couple of good answers have been provided. If any of the answers helped you with your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer. This lets the community know the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mutate_each` calculates the `sum` column wise not row wise, besides it's deprecated, you should use `mutate_all` instead; To normalize each row, you can calculate the row sums firstly and then divide all columns by it:

```
row_sum = rowSums(select(iris, -Species))
iris %>% select(-Species) %>% mutate_all(~ ./row_sum) %>% head()

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1    0.5000000   0.3431373    0.1372549  0.01960784
#2    0.5157895   0.3157895    0.1473684  0.02105263
#3    0.5000000   0.3404255    0.1382979  0.02127660
#4    0.4893617   0.3297872    0.1595745  0.02127660
#5    0.4901961   0.3529412    0.1372549  0.01960784
#6    0.4736842   0.3421053    0.1491228  0.03508772
```

---

If you prefer a single pipe:

```
iris %>% 
    mutate(row_sum = rowSums(select(., 1:4))) %>% 
    mutate_at(1:4, ~ ./row_sum) %>% 
    select(-row_sum) %>% head()

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1    0.5000000   0.3431373    0.1372549  0.01960784  setosa
#2    0.5157895   0.3157895    0.1473684  0.02105263  setosa
#3    0.5000000   0.3404255    0.1382979  0.02127660  setosa
#4    0.4893617   0.3297872    0.1595745  0.02127660  setosa
#5    0.4901961   0.3529412    0.1372549  0.01960784  setosa
#6    0.4736842   0.3421053    0.1491228  0.03508772  setosa
```

Answer (score 3):

#### mutate_if solution

```
RS <- rowSums(iris[,1:4])
iris %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(. / RS))
```

#### Output

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1    0.5000000   0.3431373    0.1372549  0.01960784  setosa
2    0.5157895   0.3157895    0.1473684  0.02105263  setosa
3    0.5000000   0.3404255    0.1382979  0.02127660  setosa
4    0.4893617   0.3297872    0.1595745  0.02127660  setosa
5    0.4901961   0.3529412    0.1372549  0.01960784  setosa
# etc
```